# Reduce can't reduce an equation without appropriate assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, assumptions

When there are three unknowns (`x`, `y`, `z`), *Mathematica* can solve it:

```
Reduce[ Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] == 1 && z != 0, {x, y, z}, 
        Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

for four variables (`x`, `y`, `z`, `t`), *Mathematica* can't return a result in reasonable time:

```
Reduce[ Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0, {x, y, z, t}, 
        Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

*Maple* can solve this quickly:

[image]

Is it possible to solve this with *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Working with such a sophisticated function as `Reduce`, if we can't get the result initially we should add possibly many assumptions. Without the `Backsubstitution` option it yielded:

```
Reduce[ Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0, {x, y, z, t}, Reals]
```

> ```
> No more memory available.
> Mathematica kernel has shut down.
> Try quitting other applications and then retry.
> ```

One simple idea which comes to consideration is supplementing the system with obvious assumptions like `x >= -1 && y >= -1 && z >= -1`. Supplemeting the system with another inequalities restricts the search space considerably.  Now we have after a bit (it took roughly `2` minutes):

```
Reduce[ Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0 && 
        x >= -1 && y >= -1 && z >= -1, {x, y, z, t}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> ```
> (-1 < x <= 0 && -1 - x < y <= 0 && -1 - x - y < z <= 0 && t == -1 - x - y - z) ||
> (-1 < x <= 0 && -1 - x < y <= 0 && -1 - x - y < z <= 0 && t == 1 + x + y + z) ||
> (-1 < x <= 0 && -1 - x < y <= 0 && 0 < z < 1 + x + y && t == -1 - x - y + z) || 
> (-1 < x <= 0 && -1 - x < y <= 0 && 0 < z < 1 + x + y && t == 1 + x + y - z) || 
> (-1 < x <= 0 && 0 < y < 1 + x && -1 - x + y < z <= 0 && t == -1 - x + y - z) || 
> (-1 < x <= 0 && 0 < y < 1 + x && -1 - x + y < z <= 0 && t == 1 + x - y + z) || 
> (-1 < x <= 0 && 0 < y < 1 + x && 0 < z < 1 + x - y && t == -1 - x + y + z) || 
> (-1 < x <= 0 && 0 < y < 1 + x && 0 < z < 1 + x - y && t == 1 + x - y - z) || 
> (0 < x < 1/6 && -1 + x < y <= 0 && -1 + x - y < z <= 0 && t == -1 + x - y - z) ||
> (0 < x < 1/6 && -1 + x < y <= 0 && -1 + x - y < z <= 0 && t == 1 - x + y + z) ||
> (0 < x < 1/6 && -1 + x < y <= 0 && 0 < z < 1 - x + y && t == -1 + x - y + z) ||
> (0 < x < 1/6 && -1 + x < y <= 0 && 0 < z < 1 - x + y && t == 1 - x + y - z) ||
> (0 < x < 1/6 && 0 < y < 1 - x && -1 + x + y < z <= 0 && t == -1 + x + y - z) ||
> (0 < x < 1/6 && 0 < y < 1 - x && -1 + x + y < z <= 0 && t == 1 - x - y + z) ||
> (0 < x < 1/6 && 0 < y < 1 - x && 0 < z < 1 - x - y && t == -1 + x + y + z) || 
> (0 < x < 1/6 && 0 < y < 1 - x && 0 < z < 1 - x - y && t == 1 - x - y - z) ||
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && -1 + x < y < 0 && -1 + x - y < z <= 0 && t == -1 + x - y - z) || 
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && -1 + x < y < 0 && -1 + x - y < z <= 0 && t == 1 - x + y + z) ||
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && -1 + x < y < 0 && 0 < z < 1 - x + y && t == -1 + x - y + z) ||
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && -1 + x < y < 0 && 0 < z < 1 - x + y && t == 1 - x + y - z) ||
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && y == 0 && -1 + x < z < 0 && t == -1 + x - z) || 
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && y == 0 && -1 + x < z < 0 && t == 1 - x + z) || 
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && y == 0 && 0 <= z < 1 - x && t == -1 + x + z) || 
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && y == 0 && 0 <= z < 1 - x && t == 1 - x - z) || 
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 - x && -1 + x + y < z <= 0 && t == -1 + x + y - z) ||
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 - x && -1 + x + y < z <= 0 && t == 1 - x - y + z) || 
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 - x && 0 < z < 1 - x - y && t == -1 + x + y + z) ||
> (1/6 <= x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 - x && 0 < z < 1 - x - y && t == 1 - x - y - z)
> ```

We can guess that an arbitrary restriction of the numbers of underlying cases behind the system appears to be a critical issue.

Another approach  is `CylindricalDecomposition` (it assumes that all variables are real):

```
CylindricalDecomposition[ Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0 && 
                          x >= -1 && y >= -1 && z >= -1, {x, y, z, t}
```

> ```
> (-1 < x <= 0 && (
>   (-1 - x < y <= 0 && (
>      (-1 - x - y < z <= 0 && (t == -1 - x - y - z || t == 1 + x + y + z)) || 
>      (0 < z < 1 + x + y && (t == -1 - x - y + z || t == 1 + x + y - z)))) || 
>   (0 < y < 1 + x && (
>      (-1 - x + y < z <= 0 && (t == -1 - x + y - z || t == 1 + x - y + z)) || 
>      (0 < z < 1 + x - y && (t == -1 - x + y + z || t == 1 + x - y - z)))))) || 
>   (0 < x < 1/6 && (
>      (-1 + x < y <= 0 && (
>        (-1 + x - y < z <= 0 && (t == -1 + x - y - z || t == 1 - x + y + z)) || 
>        (0 < z < 1 - x + y && (t == -1 + x - y + z || t == 1 - x + y - z)))) || 
>   (0 < y < 1 - x && (
>      (-1 + x + y < z <= 0 && (t == -1 + x + y - z || t == 1 - x - y + z)) || 
>      (0 < z < 1 - x - y && (t == -1 + x + y + z || t == 1 - x - y - z)))))) ||
>   (1/6 <= x < 1 && ( 
>      (-1 + x < y < 0 && ((-1 + x - y < z <= 0 && (t == -1 + x - y - z ||
>                                                   t == 1 - x + y + z)) || 
>       (0 < z < 1 - x + y && (t == -1 + x - y + z || t == 1 - x + y - z)))) || 
>       (y == 0 && ((-1 + x < z < 0 && (t == -1 + x - z || t == 1 - x + z)) || 
>                   (0 <= z < 1 - x && (t == -1 + x + z || t == 1 - x - z)))) || 
>        (0 < y < 1 - x && ((-1 + x + y < z <= 0 && (t == -1 + x + y - z || 
>     t == 1 - x - y + z)) || (0 < z < 1 - x - y && (t == -1 + x + y + z || 
>          t == 1 - x - y - z))))))
> ```

An interesting observation is that if we add also this condition `t >= -1`  the system cannot be reduced and we get `... Mathematica kernel has shut down. ...`.  We encounter this issue working with `Reduce` as well as with `CylindricalDecomposition`. However it might depend on accessible size of memory. 
In such cases we can exploit `SemialgebraicComponentInstances` yielding a sample of points in each connected component of semialgebraic set defined by system of inequalities:

```
SemialgebraicComponentInstances[ Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0 &&
                                 x >= -1 && y >= -1 && z >= -1 && t >= -1, 
                                {x, y, z, t}] // Short
```

> ```
> {{x -> -(1/2), y -> 0, z -> 0, t -> -(1/2)}, {x -> -(1/2), y -> 0, z -> 0, t -> 1/2},
>  {x -> -(1/4), y -> -(1/4), z -> 0, t -> -(1/2)}, <<49>>, 
>  {x -> 1/2, y -> 0, z -> 0, t -> -(1/2)}, {x -> 1/2, y -> 0, z -> 0, t -> 1/2}}
> ```

Comment: Strange that it splits up the $0<x<\frac16$ and $\frac16\le x<1$ cases, which are otherwise essentially identical.

Answer (score 4):

One way that works is to solve for one of the variables first.  This seems like a natural first step.  Perhaps, though, it will be considered a drawback that not all of the absolute values are expanded.  We can deal with that later, if desired.  Most importantly, though, finding the solution takes less than 0.2 seconds.

```
Reduce[Equal @@ #[[1]], {x, y, z, t}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True] & /@ 
 Solve[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0, t, Reals]

(* {(-1 < x <= 0 && -1 - x < y <= 0 && -1 - x - y < z < 1 + x + y &&
       t == 1 - Abs[x] - Abs[y] - Abs[z]) ||
    (-1 < x <= 0 && 0 < y < 1 + x && -1 - x + y < z < 1 + x - y && 
       t == 1 - Abs[x] - Abs[y] - Abs[z]) ||
    (0 < x < 1 && -1 + x < y <= 0 && -1 + x - y < z < 1 - x + y && 
       t == 1 - Abs[x] - Abs[y] - Abs[z]) ||
    (0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 - x && -1 + x + y < z < 1 - x - y && 
       t == 1 - Abs[x] - Abs[y] - Abs[z]),
    (-1 < x <= 0 && -1 - x < y <= 0 && -1 - x - y < z < 1 + x + y && 
       t == -1 + Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z]) ||
    (-1 < x <= 0 &&  0 < y < 1 + x && -1 - x + y < z < 1 + x - y && 
       t == -1 + Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z]) ||
    (0 < x < 1 && -1 + x < y <= 0 && -1 + x - y < z < 1 - x + y && 
       t == -1 + Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z]) ||
    (0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 - x && -1 + x + y < z < 1 - x - y && 
       t == -1 + Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z])}   *)
```

One can manually expand the absolute values with the following.  It it replaces an equation with the form `Abs[u]` in it by two, one with `u` plus the condition that `u >= 0` and one with `-u` plus the condition that `u < 0`.

```
absExpand = eq_Equal?(! FreeQ[#, Abs] &) :> 
  Fold[(#1 /. Abs[#2] :> #2) && #2 >= 0 || (#1 /. Abs[#2] :> -#2) && #2 < 0 &,
       eq, 
       Union @ Cases[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1, Abs[u_] :> u, 
                     Infinity]]
```

One can then take the output above and process it further with `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[Or @@ # /. absExpand, {x, y, z, t}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True] &@
 (Reduce[Equal @@ #[[1]], {x, y, z, t}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True] & /@ 
   Solve[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1 && t != 0, t, Reals])
```

It takes about 10 seconds and 200 MB in all, which considerable faster than using just a single `Reduce`.  The output looks identical to Artes's first one, with the interval `1 <= x <= 1` divided into three intervals at `0` and `1/6`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Reduce[#, {x, y, z, t}, Reals] & /@
  PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] + Abs[t] == 1, Reals]


Reduce[Abs@x + Abs@y + Abs@z + Abs@t == 1 && x < 0 && y z t != 0, {y, z, t}, Reals] || 
   Reduce[Abs@x + Abs@y + Abs@z + Abs@t == 1 && x > 0 && y z t != 0, {y, z, t}, Reals] /. 
    {Less -> LessEqual,  Greater -> GreaterEqual} // BooleanMinimize

Reduce[Abs@x + Abs@y + Abs@z + Abs@t == 1 && #, {x, y, z, t}] & /@
 (And @@@ Tuples[{# < 0, # > 0} & /@ {x, y, z, t}]) /.
 {Less -> LessEqual, Greater -> GreaterEqual, List -> Or} // BooleanMinimize
```

[image]